# T-SQL update join 1:N

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

**Table1**:

```
id  fee1    fee2
1   0.00    0.00
2   0.00    0.00
```

**Table2**:

```
id  fee_no  fee
1   A       10.00
1   B       20.00
2   A       80.00
2   B       90.00
```

SQL:

```
update a
   set a.fee1 = isnull(a.fee1, 0)
              + (case when b.fee_no ='A'
                      then cast(isnull(b.fee, 0) as decimal(30, 2))
                      else 0 end),
       a.fee2 = isnull(a.fee2, 0)
              + (case when b.fee_no ='B'
                      then cast(isnull(b.fee, 0) as decimal(30,2))
                      else 0 end)
  from table1 a
 inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id
```

After I executed this SQL, only `fee1` of `table1` is updated, while `fee2` is not. Finally I used two SQL statements to update `fee1` and `fee2` respectively.

But why doesn't this SQL statement work?

Here is create table statement:

```
create table table1(
 id    int       null,
 fee1  dec(30,2) null,
 fee2  dec(30,2) null
)
insert into table1 (id,fee1,fee2)
select 1,0,0 union
select 2,0,0

create table table2(
 id       int         null,
 fee_no   varchar(10) null,
 fee      dec(30,2)   null
)
insert into table2 (id,fee_no,fee)
select 1,'A',10 union
select 1,'B',20 union
select 2,'A',80 union
select 2,'B',90
```

Comment: Your update reads `case when c.fee_no ='B'` but there is no table alias `c` assigned in your query?

Comment: sorry, it's clerical error. I've fix it

Comment: Can you post your SQL? I bet the second `update` for `fee2` has updated incorrect values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is that each row of `table1` is updated twice. However when the second update takes place, it operates on the *original* data of the table. So, `fee2` is set back to `0`.

To properly `UPDATE` you need a query like this:

```
update a
   set a.fee1 = isnull(a.fee1, 0)
              + (case when b.fee_no ='A'
                      then cast(isnull(b.fee, 0) as decimal(30, 2))
                      else 0 end),
       a.fee2 = isnull(a.fee2, 0)
              + (case when c.fee_no ='B'
                      then cast(isnull(c.fee, 0) as decimal(30,2))
                      else 0 end)
 from table1 a
 inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id and b.fee_no = 'A'
 inner join table2 c on a.id = c.id and c.fee_no = 'B'
```

Comment: why didn't the same thing happened on `fee1`? what's  the difference between `feel` and  `fee2` in `update` and `select` query?